# Create a parametrized List from a Class variable

Tags: java

I want to create a list from a `Class` variable.

```
...
Class clazz = someObject.getClass(); 
List<clazz> myList = new ArrayList<clazz>(); // this line is a compilation error
...
```

How I can do it?

EDIT: I think you are getting it wrong. For example, if `someObject` is a `Car`, then `myList` type should be `List<Car>`. I want to treat my clazz variable as a type, in some way.

Comment: Use _generics_ - `public <T> List<T> getList(final T t)`.

Comment: Can you add a small example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

As Boris the Spider pointed out in the comments it **actually is possible** by using a generic method, but with a slight modification:

Instead of using the normal `Class` object, use the generic version `Class<? extends [Type of someObject]>`.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Test t = new Test();
    Class<? extends Test> testClass = t.getClass();
    List<? extends Test> list = createListOfType(testClass);
}

private static <T> List<T> createListOfType(Class<T> type){
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Of course you can also just go with

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Test t = new Test();
    List<? extends Test> list = createListOfType(t);
}

private static <T> List<T> createListOfType(T element){
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

OLD POST:

**You can't.**

You can't, because Java needs to know the generic type you want to use for the `ArrayList` at compile time. It's possible to use `Object` as type though.

Comment: This is wrong. You can easily use a generic method to create a `List` of the appropriate type.

Comment: true, but then you still need to pass a type argument to the generic method somehow and you can't do that, only based on the `class` object. I'll clarify that in the answer

Comment: ok, i just checked it myself and you're totally right. When one uses the generic version of `Class` (`Class<T>`) then it works

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variable name as the type. You must use `Class` instead of clazz

```
List<Class> myList = new ArrayList<Class>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind about [`type erasure`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The Obvious answer is,

```
List<Class> myList = new ArrayList<Class>();
```

You can only specify the type of Object (for compiler). You can't see them at Run Time :)